# Get proper page orientation from Google Document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am using the Google document AI API to OCR some documents but I have an issue.

OCR works well but I would like it to tell me the orientation of the document, so whether it is upside down or rotated left or right.

Since the OCR works, the process is capable of knowning this information. It is however not returned in the output JSON of the API. As far as I can see it *should* be in the page "orientation" property but I always get `"orientation": "PAGE_UP"`.

For the incorrect (upside down) sample I'm also noticing a transforms property.

```json
"transforms": [
    {
        "rows": 2,
        "cols": 3,
        "type": 6,
        "data": "AAAAAAAA8L8HXBQzJqahvAAAAAAAgFlAB1wUMyamoTwAAAAAAADwv/7//////zZA"
    }
]
```

But I don't know how to translate this into rotation information, it is not the same value for all upside down documents.

**Request Info**

POST https://eu-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxx/locations/eu/processors/xxxxx:process

Processor: Document OCR, pretrained-ocr-v1.2-2022-11-10

**Upright Sample Request**

```json
{
    "rawDocument": {
        "content": "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",
        "mimeType": "image/png"
    },
    "processOptions": {
        "ocrConfig": {
            "enableImageQualityScores": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Upside-down Sample Request**

```json
{
    "rawDocument": {
        "content": "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",
        "mimeType": "image/png"
    },
    "processOptions": {
        "ocrConfig": {
            "enableImageQualityScores": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @André Kops, Could you check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#orientation)[1] and [document](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#matrix)[2] ? I have replicated the scenario with a sample document with different orientation, I could see the respective orientation if we scroll down in the json response. If this not solved your issue, can u provide sample image and little bit more details ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh added my samples in the question.  These both return PAGE_UP as the orientation, at least on page level. On block level there are differences but I've found with other sample files it is not consistent enough to base the entire page on.

Comment: Hi @André Kops, As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-processor), the **`image_content`** ,  is the valid Inline document content, represented as a stream of bytes. It is represented as the **[base64 encoding](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/base64)** (ASCII string) of your binary image data, which is different for different images or documents. Is this helpful for you ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh I saw that but then I need to transform it into pdf as that is what I’m starting with and want to end up with. Also the image is much larger than the original. My hope was/is that I could just rotate the original pdf, I’ve got the code lying around for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the API Spec documentation, it looks like this `transforms` field is compatible with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) formatting for Matrix Transformations.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#matrix

I agree that the orientation always showing as `PAGE_UP` is confusing. I'm going to double-check to make sure this field is working as intended.

Comment: I have considered using the transforms field but I have no idea how to translate that into the orientation. It doesn't always use the same value for upside down documents and I can't find how to parse it to get the actual rotation used.

Comment: I have added simple sample cases in the question now. Using those, I think you'll find it is not working as intended.